# Eclipse Subversive add new files to version control

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Is there a way of making Eclipse Subversive **not** to add new files to version control? Team -> Ignored Resources is not an option, because I want **explictly** add all new files independently of they extension. Including source code files (.cpp, .java, .py, whatever).

In other words, I want a behaviour similar to command line SVN. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found an answer to this, but I was experiencing the same issue after upgrading to Eclipse Kepler and switching from Subclipse to Subversive. Here is what I found to "fix" this issue (especially annoying issue when the build artifacts shouldn't be committed!):

Window->Preferences->Team->SVN
  General Tab
    Resource Selection
      Deselect the option "Check new resources in the commit dialog"